# System cannot boot, continuously scanning btrfs filesystem

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk, btrfs, busybox

On the previous boot I installed [HAL](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal/) to make amazon prime video streaming work, which it did (mostly), but after reboot the system could not pull itself up all the way to BASH and drops to a failed busybox.

It is entirely possible the failure to boot and HAL are not related. It drops down after repeatedly saying it is scanning, and then listing tons of I/O errors. I am pretty sure that the partition is an ext4 and not btrfs, but I could be wrong as I don't recall which one I clicked during install. Not to mention I've heard btrfs is good for old HDDs. It could be the aging hard drive. I'm not sure. The system is an old Dell laptop from circa 2006 running Linux Mint 15 64bit, using xfce.

I don't mind reinstalling at all, but I would like to be able to save my files if possible. I tried mounting the drive from the Linux Mint install CD, but it failed hard too. Telling me it couldn't even run the install program.

Note that I am writing this from Windows Vista 32bit which came with the laptop and is located on another partition on the same drive - and does not show any signs of errors (I hope...).

Comment: First thing I'd do in any case involving suspected HDD problems: boot from CD, DVD, USB or whatever, don't even try mounting the disk, but instead connect some external storage, e.g. a USB drive or another computer via network. Then use `ddrescue` to store as much of the hard disk content as possible on that external device. Then you can investigate ways to possibly recover or reinstall the system.